# How I can use vue-awesome-swiper with slideTo()?

Tags: vue.js

I have a some project [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-kcz1m?fontsize=14)

I use [vue-awesome-swiper](https://github.surmon.me/vue-awesome-swiper/)

I do as an [thumbs example](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper/blob/master/examples/31-thumbs-gallery-loop.vue) and [slideTo example](https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-awesome-swiper/blob/master/examples/41-virtual-slides.vue)

```
<swiper :options="swiperOptionThumbs" class="gallery-thumbs" ref="swiperThumbs">
  <swiper-slide class="slide-1">1.1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-2">1.2</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-3">1.3</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-4">1.4</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-5">1.5</swiper-slide>
</swiper>

<swiper :options="swiperOptionTop" class="gallery-top" ref="swiperTop">
  <swiper-slide class="slide-1">1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-2">2</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-3">3</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-4">4</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide class="slide-5">5</swiper-slide>
</swiper>
```

**Scripts:**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      swiperOptionTop: {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 1
      },
      swiperOptionThumbs: {
        spaceBetween: 10,
        slidesPerView: 4,
        slideToClickedSlide: true
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    swiper() {
      return this.$refs.swiperOptionTop.swiper;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toSlide(i) {
      this.$refs.swiperOptionTop.swiper.slideTo(i);
    },
    toNext() {
      console.log("S>>> next " + this.$refs.swiperOptionTop.swiper);
      this.$refs.swiperOptionTop.swiper.slideNext();
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const swiperTop = this.$refs.swiperTop.swiper;
      const swiperThumbs = this.$refs.swiperThumbs.swiper;
      swiperTop.controller.control = swiperThumbs;
      swiperThumbs.controller.control = swiperTop;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

But nothing effects.

**Question:**  How can I set the slideTo method or use thumbs for slider (vue awesome swiper slider)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your codesanbox, I found the following errors:

1.Remove the `.native` suffix in `@click.native`

```
<button @click="toSlide(0)">To Slide 1</button>
<button @click="toSlide(1)">To Slide 2</button>
<button @click="toSlide(2)">To Slide 3</button>
```

2.The component pointed to by your `$refs` is incorrect

```
toSlide(i) {
  // Wrong ref
  // this.$refs.swiperOptionTop.swiper.slideTo(i)
  this.$refs.swiperTop.swiper.slideTo(i, 0);
}
```

There are also wrong refs in other places, you can check it yourself.

After modifying the above error, you can find that the `slideTo` method can be executed normally, I hope I can help you:)

Comment: Couldn't find ref.swiper, but could find ref.$swiper.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that if you use pug in templates, you must use the following entry.

```
PUG
    Swiper(
           :options="swiperOptions" // { it's options }
           ref="swiperTop" // your reference name
          )
           SwiperSlide(v-for="(item, key) in images" :key="key") // your slides
JS
this.$refs.swiperTop.$swiper.slideTo(key)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you did not make a mistake when writing the code:

1. Error 1:

```html
<div
  class="swiper-container"   //xxxx----custom label naming cannot be ”swiperr-container" or the class name in the component“
>
  <swiper class="swiper" :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiper">
    <div
      class="swiper-stations" v-for="(item, index) in stations"
      :key="index"
    >  //xxxx----Div tags cannot be nested between  <swiper > and <swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide></swiper-slide>
    </div>
  </swiper>
</div>
```

2. You have to follow steps like this
   [image: code example]